# How to plot a sparse matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have a large sparse matrix (100 rows 8000 columns) and I would like to represent it graphically. I found on internet this representation of a matrix of this kind:

[image]

But it didnt specify how the image was obtained. I have tried using plot.matrix package and SparseM package but I still did not find the answer.

Comment: When you say "sparse matrix" what kind if object are you referring to? Something from the Matrix package?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `image()` function in R:

```
# Create a matrix with random 0s and 1s
pseudo.data <- rbinom(100 * 8000, 1, 0.5)
pseudo.data <- matrix(pseudo.data, nrow = 100)

# plot the matrix
image(t(pseudo.data), col = c("white", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work well with a huge matrix.

Comment: Works well for a 100x8000 matrix. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something along these lines:

```r
  library(tidyverse)

generatedMatrix <- matrix(rnorm(900), ncol = 30)>.5

generatedMatrix %>% as.vector %>% 
  tibble(value = ., row = rep(1:nrow(generatedMatrix), times = ncol(generatedMatrix)),
                                         col = rep(1: ncol(generatedMatrix), each = nrow(generatedMatrix))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = row, y = col, colour = value)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black','white'))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
  library(tidyverse)

generatedMatrix <- matrix(rbinom(900,size = 1,prob = .5), ncol = 30)

generatedMatrix %>% as.vector %>% 
  tibble(value = ., row = rep(1:nrow(generatedMatrix), times = ncol(generatedMatrix)),
                                         col = rep(1: ncol(generatedMatrix), each = nrow(generatedMatrix))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = row, y = col, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(size = 2) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'black',high = 'white')+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work well with a huge matrix.

Comment: I mean...kind of... :D

Comment: Whats the use of such a plot? xD